# RxJS multiple subscriptions for Observable.Interval

Tags: javascript, reactive-extensions-js, rxjs

Is there any solution like following one for RxJS?
[Is it possible to invoke subscribers's OnNexts on different threads in Rx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821404/is-it-possible-to-invoke-subscriberss-onnexts-on-different-threads-in-rx)

P.S. My first, naive approach(in CoffeeScript) had obviously failed:

```
hObs = Rx.Observable.interval(35000)
    .startWith(-1)
    .select(moment().format("D MMMM, HH:mm:ss"))
    .publish()

hObs.subscribe((x)->console.log(x))
hObs.connect()
hObs.subscribe((x)->console.log(x, 1))
hObs.connect()
```

Second subscription returns nothing for 35s interval, and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.select` expects a function, not a value. The following works:

```
(function() {
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var stream = Rx.Observable.interval(35000)
    .startWith(-1)
    .select(function(){ return moment().format("D MMMM, HH:mm:ss") });

    stream.subscribe(function(value) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "subscriber 1: "+value;
        list.appendChild(li); 
    });    
    stream.subscribe(function(value) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "subscriber 2: "+value;
        list.appendChild(li); 
    });
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9EjSQ/43/

Notice that you don't need to call `connect()` twice, typically you call it only once. It is better to use "automatic" `connect()` by calling `.publish().refCount()` at the end of the observable chain. That would create a ConnectableObservable, in other words a "hot observable" (see https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables). In this case, we didn't need a hot observable.

In coffeescript:

```
list = document.getElementById("list")
stream = Rx.Observable.interval(35000)
.startWith(-1)
.select(-> moment().format("D MMMM, HH:mm:ss"))

stream.subscribe((value) ->
    li = document.createElement("li")
    li.innerHTML = "subscriber 1: " + value
    list.appendChild(li)
)
stream.subscribe((value) ->
    li = document.createElement("li")
    li.innerHTML = "subscriber 2: " + value
    list.appendChild(li)
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9EjSQ/44/